# Need a wiki etc

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We need to enhance our posting guidelines, especially for newcomers. Users should be encouraged to google first and then post questions for which they have been unable to find answers.

Users should also be encouraged to search for existing questions before posing a new one.

Secondly, a wiki with some basic definitions and links to popular questions will help newcomers as well as old-timers.

Every new person visiting the site and asking very basic, oft-repeated, often ill-formed questions can get tiresome. Some of these questions seem insincere and more intent on displaying the author's cleverness than anything else.

Comment: We've [How do I ask a good question?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [How should we deal with Google questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/260388) may also help you.

Comment: Also see [Private beta extended - please focus on quality](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/92/2995).